# Use component variable in style attribute

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am attempting to use a component variable in the attribute `style` but I get compile errors when I do so. What the issue here?

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:427)

```
<template>
<div>
    <!-- THe below is valid -->
    <img v-bind:src="$IMG_PATH + '/carousel1.jpeg'"/>

    <!-- The below wont compile: has syntax errors? -->
    <p v-bind:style="background-image: url('$IMG_PATH + \'/carousel1.jpeg\''));">Foo</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>

Vue.prototype.$IMG_PATH = './foo/img'

export default {
    ...
}
</script>
</style>
```

Comment: From the CSS side, it should be `backgrond-image: url()` , not `background-image(url())`

Comment: @Vucko thanks thats part of the problem but I still get compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [v-bind:style](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles) wrong, use:

```
<p v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + $IMG_PATH + '/carousel1.jpeg)' }"></p>
```

Example:

```js
Vue.prototype.$IMG_PATH = 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/701'

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```css
p {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + $IMG_PATH + '/beer-main-0-1496757601.jpg)' }">foobar</p>
</div>
```